# How can I mass implement Deserialize for all types that implement a specific trait?

Tags: rust, deserialization, traits, serde

I am deserializing a YAML config file with Serde. For most structs I deserialize into, things are quite simple — there's a one-to-one relationship between the fields of the structs and the properties in my YAML file.

In a few cases, things are a bit more complicated. For these, the properties in the YAML file are better viewed as parameters to the constructor. The actual struct will have different fields, calculated from those.

For these cases, I have written separate config structs that I deserialize into. For simplicity, consider this silly example:

```
struct Message {
    text: String,
}

impl Message {
    fn from_config(config: MessageConfig) -> Message {
        Message {
            text: format!("{} {}", config.first_half, config.second_half),
        }
    }
}

#[derive(Deserialize)]
struct MessageConfig {
    first_half: String,
    second_half: String,
}
```

To have Serde do the conversion from `MessageConfig` to `Message` for me, I implemented `Deserialize` for `Message`:

```
impl<'de> Deserialize<'de> for Message {
    fn deserialize<D>(deserializer: D) -> Result<Message, D::Error>
    where
        D: Deserializer<'de>,
    {
        MessageConfig::deserialize(deserializer).map(|config| Message::from_config(config))
    }
}
```

This works, but there would be a lot of copy pasting of the deserialization code involved if I were to do this for every struct, so I figured I should make a trait out of it:

```
use serde::{Deserialize, Deserializer};
use serde_json;
#[macro_use]
extern crate serde_derive;

trait Configurable {
    type Config;
    fn from_config(config: Self::Config) -> Self;
}

impl<'de, T, C> Deserialize<'de> for T
where
    T: Configurable<Config = C>,
    C: Deserialize<'de>,
{
    fn deserialize<D>(deserializer: D) -> Result<T, D::Error>
    where
        D: Deserializer<'de>,
    {
        Self::Config::deserialize(deserializer).map(|config| Self::from_config(config))
    }
}

struct Message {
    text: String,
}

impl<'de> Configurable for Message {
    type Config = MessageConfig;

    fn from_config(config: MessageConfig) -> Message {
        Message {
            text: format!("{} {}", config.first_half, config.second_half),
        }
    }
}

#[derive(Deserialize)]
struct MessageConfig {
    first_half: String,
    second_half: String,
}
```

However, the compiler is not happy about this:

```
error[E0119]: conflicting implementations of trait `_IMPL_DESERIALIZE_FOR_MessageConfig::_serde::Deserialize<'_>` for type `std::boxed::Box<_>`:
  --> src/lib.rs:11:1
   |
11 | / impl<'de, T, C> Deserialize<'de> for T
12 | | where
13 | |     T: Configurable<Config = C>,
14 | |     C: Deserialize<'de>,
...  |
21 | |     }
22 | | }
   | |_^
   |
   = note: conflicting implementation in crate `serde`:
           - impl<'de, T> _IMPL_DESERIALIZE_FOR_MessageConfig::_serde::Deserialize<'de> for std::boxed::Box<T>
             where T: _IMPL_DESERIALIZE_FOR_MessageConfig::_serde::Deserialize<'de>;
   = note: downstream crates may implement trait `Configurable` for type `std::boxed::Box<_>`

error[E0210]: type parameter `T` must be used as the type parameter for some local type (e.g. `MyStruct<T>`)
  --> src/lib.rs:11:1
   |
11 | / impl<'de, T, C> Deserialize<'de> for T
12 | | where
13 | |     T: Configurable<Config = C>,
14 | |     C: Deserialize<'de>,
...  |
21 | |     }
22 | | }
   | |_^ type parameter `T` must be used as the type parameter for some local type
   |
   = note: only traits defined in the current crate can be implemented for a type parameter
```

The error messages make little sense to me. What does `Box` have to do with anything? And is it somehow possible to make this trait work?

Comment: @Shepmaster I don't think it's a duplicate. The suggested dup: A struct has a field that references a trait. How do I deserialize? This question: I want to mass implement Deserialize for all types that implement a specific trait.

Comment: If all of your structs have the same implementation for deserialization, then why not  make them the same actual struct (or all contain the same struct) and implement `Deserialize` for that? If they *aren't* the same, then what's the benefit of adding extra indirection?

Comment: The error is relatively straight-forward. Serde [implements `Deserialize` for `Box<T>`](https://docs.rs/serde/1.0.84/serde/trait.Deserialize.html#impl-Deserialize%3C%27de%3E-90). Your implementation covers for `T`, which might be a `Box<T>`. A user of both crates could construct a type that could be deserialized as either your code or the one in Serde. This is disallowed.

Comment: @Shepmaster Maybe I am doing a basic mistake here. I thought by specifying `where T: Configurable<Config = C>` my implementation of `Deserialize` would only cover implementors of `Configurable`. `Box<T>` is not an implementor of `Configurable`, so I figured there wouldn't be a problem.

Comment: What prevents someone from implementing `Configurable` for `Box<MyOwnType>` when `MyOwnType` also implements `Deserialize`?

Comment: Oh. Did not think about that. Thanks. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if there's a way to define such a broad trait without causing conflicting implementations. What you could do is use a macro to avoid repetition:

```
use serde::{Deserialize, Deserializer};
use serde_json;

use serde_json::Error;

#[macro_use]
extern crate serde_derive;

struct Message {
    text: String,
}

#[derive(Deserialize)]
struct MessageConfig {
    first_half: String,
    second_half: String,
}

impl Message {
    fn from_config(config: MessageConfig) -> Message {
        Message {
            text: format!("{} {}", config.first_half, config.second_half),
        }
    }
}

macro_rules! derive_configurable_serializer {
    ( $t:ident, $c:ident ) => {
        impl<'de> Deserialize<'de> for $t {
            fn deserialize<D>(deserializer: D) -> Result<$t, D::Error>
            where
                D: Deserializer<'de>,
            {
                $c::deserialize(deserializer).map(|config| $t::from_config(config))
            }
        }
    };
}

derive_configurable_serializer!(Message, MessageConfig);

fn main() -> Result<(), Error> {
    let data = r#"{ "first_half": "John", "second_half": "Doe" }"#;

    let p: Message = serde_json::from_str(data)?;

    println!("Hello, {}!", p.text);

    Ok(())
}
```

Comment: Nice idea with a macro, and thanks for showing how to do it! I don't understand what's up with the conflicting implementations, though. There is no type that implements both Configurable and Deserialize from some other source.

Comment: @Anders honestly - I don't know. I tried finding a solution with the trait, got various error messages. Maybe someone with a deeper understanding of Rust traits can explain how to do it / why it isn't possible.