# Infinite recursion in Rust derive macro?

Tags: macros, rust, infinite-recursion

I have made the following attampt at a derive macro in Rust:

```
extern crate proc_macro;

use crate::proc_macro::TokenStream;
use quote::quote;
use syn;

#[proc_macro_derive(DeserializeConfigurable)]
pub fn deserialize_configurable_derive(input: TokenStream) -> TokenStream {
    let ast: syn::DeriveInput = syn::parse(input).unwrap();
    let name = &ast.ident;
    let gen = quote! {
        impl<'de> Deserialize<'de> for #name {
            fn deserialize<D>(deserializer: D) -> Result<#name, D::Error>
            where
                D: Deserializer<'de>,
            {
                let config = <#name as Configurable>::Config::deserialize(deserializer)?;
                Ok(#name::from_config(config))
            }
        }
    };
    gen.into()
}
```

The goal is to provide a specific blanket implementation for `deserialize` based on another trait, `Configurable`.

However, the compiler has the following complaint regarding my quote statement:

> recursion limit reached while expanding the macro `stringify`

I don't see the recursion here. I am not even using `stringify`! What is calling what in infinity here?

Comment: I have deliberately not included the definition of the trait `Configurable` in the question, since my understanding is that the compiler does not use it anyway (it's in another crate and not in scope). Let me know if that was a mistake, and I will add it.

Comment: Why are you using a macro for this? Wouldn't a simple impl work? ```impl<'de, T: Configurable> Deserialize<'de> for T```

Comment: @Wazner See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54013125/how-can-i-mass-implement-deserialize-for-all-types-that-implement-a-specific-tra).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying to compile this locally gives this full error message:

```
error: recursion limit reached while expanding the macro `stringify`
  --> src/lib.rs:13:15
   |
13 |       let gen = quote! {
   |  _______________^
14 | |         impl<'de> Deserialize<'de> for #name {
15 | |             fn deserialize<D>(deserializer: D) -> Result<#name, D::Error>
16 | |             where
...  |
22 | |         }
23 | |     };
   | |_____^
   |
   = help: consider adding a `#![recursion_limit="128"]` attribute to your crate
   = note: this error originates in a macro outside of the current crate (in Nightly builds, run with -Z external-macro-backtrace for more info)                                                                                                                                 

error: aborting due to previous error
```

Putting the following as the first line of the crate makes the error go away. My guess is that the default recursion_limit is simply too low for a macro this complex (which IMO isn't that complex). I'm sure there's a good reason, and I'm glad the error message contained the solution:

```
#![recursion_limit="128"]
```

Comment: Oh, now I feel stupid. I got that to, but I couldn't imagine the stack would actually run out for something simple like this. So I just assumed there was an infinite recursion going on.

Comment: *I'm sure there's a good reason* — yes, which is why [the quote documentation explicitly tells people about it](https://docs.rs/quote/0.6.10/quote/#recursion-limit)