# Cannot understand this error: type parameter `T` must be covered by another type when it appears before the first local type

Tags: templates, rust, compiler-errors, type-conversion, traits

When I try the code bellow (this is a small example to reproduce my problem), I have this error from the compiler:

```
error[E0210]: type parameter `T` must be covered by another type when it appears before the first local type (`Message`)
```

```rust
use serde::{Serialize, Deserialize};

// A simple struct that can be serialized and deserialized
#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct MyStruct(u64, String);

// A struct Message that can be converted into any deserializable object
struct Message(String);

impl<T: for<'a> Deserialize<'a>> TryFrom<Message> for T {
    type Error = serde_json::Error;
    fn try_from(value: Message) -> Result<Self, Self::Error> {
        serde_json::from_str(value.0)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let my_message = Message(
        serde_json::to_string(MyStruct(123, "Hello".to_string()))
    );
    
    let result_from_message = MyStruct::TryFrom(my_message).unwrap();
    println!("{result_from_message:?}");
}
```

I do not quite understand it, may I have some help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I mass implement Deserialize for all types that implement a specific trait?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54013125/how-can-i-mass-implement-deserialize-for-all-types-that-implement-a-specific-tra)

Comment: Nitpick: `for<'a> Deserialize<'a>` => `DeserializeOwned`.

Comment: Have you read the [error code explanation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/error-index.html#E0210) and [the](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1023-rebalancing-coherence.md) [RFCs](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/2451-re-rebalancing-coherence.html) referred by it?

Comment: Basically, you're trying to implement a trait you don't own (`TryFrom`) for a type you don't own (`T`), which is not allowed in Rust.

Comment: You could get around it by implementing `TryInto<T>` for `Message`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help everyone, I think I get it now!

I finally rethink my code this way:

```rust
use serde::de::DeserializeOwned;
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};

#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct MyStruct(u64, String);

struct Message(String);

impl Message {
    fn into<T: DeserializeOwned>(self) -> Result<T, serde_json::Error> {
        serde_json::from_str(&self.0)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let message =
        Message(serde_json::to_string(&MyStruct(58, "Hello, World!".to_string())).unwrap());

    let my_struct = message.into::<MyStruct>().unwrap();
    println!("{my_struct:?}");
}
```